# What is the complex conjugate of the complex $SU(2)$ doublet $(a+ib \quad c+id)^T$?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-algebras

What is the complex conjugate of the following $SU(2)$ doublet :
\begin{pmatrix}a+ib\\c+id\end{pmatrix}

where the first element is the complex variable $a+ib$, and the second element is the complex variable $c+id$, where $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ are real.

Apparently, there would a special rule, for unknown reason, that would prevent to just take the transpose and replace $+i$ by $-i$.

Comment: Please refer to the [Guidlines for question titles](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9687/guidelines-for-good-use-of-rm-latex-in-question-titles).

Comment: It might help to explain the context for the question you're asking.

Comment: The context is Higgs field, which expresses as a doublet of isospin as \begin{pmatrix}\phi_1+i\phi_2\\\phi_3+i\phi_4\end{pmatrix}. I will like to write down the lagrangian, but for that I need to know how to write down the complex conjugate of this isospin doublet. According to : https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/463026/electric-charge-of-the-higgs-field/463094#463094 the conjugate of Higgs doublet will make appear $\phi_1-i\phi_2$ with charge -1. So I'm not sure that it will appear at the first element of the conjugate.

Comment: apparently, the complex conjugate is just \begin{pmatrix}a-ib ; c-id\end{pmatrix}, so there is nothing particular. Sorry for the question.